Does anything go wrong in the lambda cube if we forbid reductions of the bodies of abstractions?
On the wikipedia page for the Lambda cube, there are five inference rules that define beta reduction:
$$\frac{}{(\lambda x:A.B)C \to_\beta B[C/x]}\; (1)$$
$$\frac{B\to_\beta B'}{\lambda x:A.B \to_\beta \lambda x:A.B'}\; (2)$$
$$\frac{A\to_\beta A'}{\lambda x:A.B \to_\beta \lambda x:A'.B}\; (3)$$
$$\frac{B\to_\beta B'}{\Pi x:A.B \to_\beta \Pi x:A.B'}\; (4)$$
$$\frac{A\to_\beta A'}{\Pi x:A.B \to_\beta \Pi x:A'.B}\; (5)$$
In most programming languages, reductions don't apply to function bodies.  Does anything go wrong if we leave out rule (2)?  What about rule (4)?

Absolutely right, thanks.  Fixed.

For an example of reduction under binders specific to the minimal pure type systems you were asking about, the counterexample has to involve the conversion rule, because that's where beta reduction is used in the system:
$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A:B \quad B=_\beta B' \quad \Gamma \vdash B':s}{\Gamma \vdash A:B'} \quad \rm (Conversion)$$
If you restrict beta reduction, then fewer terms will type check. A counterexample must involve functions appearing in types, placing us somewhere around $F_\omega$. Consider this polymorphic identity function parameterized by a function on types:
$$\mathrm{id} := (\lambda (f : \mathrm{Type}\to\mathrm{Type}). \lambda (x : f\;\mathrm{int}). x) : \Pi (f : \mathrm{Type}\to\mathrm{Type}). f\;\mathrm{int} \to f \;\mathrm{int}$$
If you apply it to $\lambda (t : \mathrm{Type}). t$, the result has type $T := (\lambda (t : \mathrm{Type}). t)\;\mathrm{int} \to (\lambda (t : \mathrm{Type}). t)\;\mathrm{int}$. Note that function types are $\Pi$-types: $A\to B = \Pi(x:A). B$ where $x$ does not occur in $B$. So converting the above term of type $T$ as a term of type $\mathrm{int}\to\mathrm{int}$ involves a beta reduction under $\Pi$.

While top-level reduction may be a natural mode of executing the lambda calculus as a programming language, that is only one specific and narrow usage of "reduction". Compilation and optimization are other processes that may easily rely on reduction under binders (not only above $F_\omega$, anywhere in the lambda cube, or even outside of it).
Before being a programming language, the lambda calculus started out as a model of logic. Mathematicians beta-reduce under binders all the time: whenever there are variables involved and we replace a function by its definition. For a dramatic example you may want to rewrite under a sum $\sum_{i} x_i^2$, which can be formalized in type theory as an operator $\sum : (I\to\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ (for some finite set $I$) applied to a lambda $\sum (\lambda i. x_i^2)$. Behold, beta reduction under a lambda:
$$\sum(\lambda i. x_i^2) = \sum(\lambda i. (\lambda z. z\cdot z)\;x_i) = \sum(\lambda i.x_i\cdot x_i)$$
